# bug in Fedora 28, Close all Application after unlock

Tags: fedora-28

Last night I updated fedora from version 26 to 28 and now after locking the screen and unlocking again, **all applications are closed** which were open before being locked!
What to do?

edited: after screen lock, log Out session

Answer (score 0):

solve my issu
This problem for **gdm** (Gnome Display Manager).
Change i whit **ldm**

```
 1. # dnf install lightdm lightdm-gtk
 2. # systemctl disable gdm.service.
 3. # systemctl enable lightdm.service.
 4. Then restart your linux.
```

this command show current Display Manager

```
# ls -l /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service
```